# Weird Behaviour with Bootstrapping Circuit

Tags: h-bridge, prototyping, troubleshooting, gate-driving

I'm trying to make a 3 phase BLDC driver and picked up some [FAN7888](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FA/FAN7888.html)s since they're inexpensive gate drives with all 3 phases on one chip. I read the relevant datasheets and application notes and breadboarded the following circuit to test one of the phases:

[image]

This circuit *mostly* works -- if I alternate pressing SW1 and SW2 the LED turns firmly off and on as expected. However, if I leave the circuit untouched, the LED turns on brightly by itself and if I measure that node, it's 7.5V; Q1 has turned itself on despite the inputs being grounded.

Secondly, I never measure more than 12V at the gate of Q1 which means it's not actually bootstrapping. This is after I ground Q4 to let it charge.

I'm at a bit of a loss of what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it. I've read piles of material but this is the first time I've actually tried implementing one so I'm probably caught on some 'gotcha'. I've verified all the parts are working and that everything is wired correctly and in spec. Why is this not working?

Comment: What are the voltages at HO1, VB1, and VS1 when both inputs are grounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's the way R5 is hooked up.

There is a path from +12V through VB1 to VS1 then through R5, LED1, and R3 to ground that will provide some bias to the high side driver. Since Q1-S is not hooked to VS1 (like it should be), but to the divider of R5 and LED1+R3 to ground, Q1-S will be lower than Q1-G. This apparently will turn Q1 on enough to put some current through LED1.

Comment: This got it working much better! The bootstrapping is visible on the scope now. That node still floats to about 1.7V when left alone though, but turning on Q4 prevents that and is something I have to do anyways to charge the cap.

Answer (score 3):

Capacitive bootstrap circuits on gate driver chips *depend* on the fact that the control signals are switching *continuously* at a relatively high rate (10s of kHz, typically). Otherwise, the bootstrap charge (voltage) leaks away.

A static test like what you have set up isn't going to demonstrate the bootstrap effect at all.

Comment: I wonder what the purpose of R5 is.  It slows down the bootstrap action,  and also could be the reason it is not shutting down when both inputs are low.

Comment: R5 is a dummy load. I was having some issues where I would push one of the buttons and I would get square oscillations and a lot of heat generation on Q1 and current consumption - probably its turning on but can't stay on. I stuck it there to protect components while I was debugging. With it there it doesn't do that

Comment: 1k Ohm is way too big for a "dummy load." What you were seeing was likely "shoot-through" where both MOSFETs are conducting at the same time. To build a successful motor controller, you need to figure out why that is and adjust dead times to fix it.

Comment: What Dave said. Also, you should NOT be using a 1N4004 for a kHz switched circuit.. they have quite lethargic reverse recovery time (about 5usec typically, IIRC). You can use a UF4004.

Comment: gsills' answer solved my problem, but your comments helped out. I know 1k is several orders of magnitude larger than a motor, but it was the lowest 1/4W resistor I had that was rated for shoot through. I'm also aware that 1N4004 is a low performance diode and are only for test jig purposes. Not a permanent part by any means.